# Could a planet be toss from a galaxy just like it's theorized rogue stars are?

Tags: planet, intergalactic-space

According to this,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_star

Rogue stars are theorized to be the intergalactic space because of this,

> The way these stars arise is still a mystery, but the most common
>   theory is that the collision of two or more galaxies can toss some
>   stars out into the vast empty regions of intergalactic space.

Could a planet be toss from a galaxy just like it's theorized rogue stars are?

Comment: First sentence of quote should tell you the answer. :-)

Comment: A related question : [How are rogue planets discovered ?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-are-rogue-planets-discovered?rq=1)

Comment: Just curious:is there any particular reason you think a star could be ejected but a planet couldn't be?

Comment: I think not, but since I'm not an astronomer there might be things I dont understand that make it impossible and I ignore them. They are structurally different in composition, size, etc.